# Import Eclipse Android Project in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I want to import eclipse android project into IntelliJ.
The problem is, that in the Import Module wizard (*Import project from external model*), I can not choose Eclipse because it is not listed. Flash Builder, Gradle, or Maven are listed but eclipse is missing.

[image: that s how it looks like]

Comment: You should export project to gradle (from eclipse) then import it as a gradle project in Android Studio ;)

Comment: @user974801 wrong, Intellij IDEA supports import from Eclipse format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have no `Eclipse Integration` plugin. In Intellij IDEA go to the `Settings` -> `Plugins` and install it from repository.